# GeoDjango туториал

Tags: django, postgresql, gis, postgis

Окружение - Win 10, Python 2.7

Прохожу GeoDjango tutorial. Установил PostgreSQL 9.5, psycopg2, GEOS, PROJ.4, GDAL (последние три через OSGeo4W) and postGIS 2.2.

Дошел до раздела Create a Spatial Database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#create-a-spatial-database)

И дальше в тупике, потому что зеленый в PostgreSQL и не понимаю, что делать и где делать.

В начале мы имеем инструкцию:

```
$ createdb -T template_postgis geodjango
```

Но в то же время по ссылке: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#spatialdb-template

мы получаем такую инструкцию:

```
$ createdb  <db name>
$ psql <db name>
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Я пытался вводить эти команды в оболочке после ввода команды рsql, но ничего не происходит, я не вижу никакого ответа, что что-то там было создано и т.п.

просто идет переход на новую строчку postgres=#

Объясните, пжлст, чайнику какие команды и где надо вводить.

P.S. и еще одна непонятная штука - когда я устанавливал PostgreSQL Я оставил логин как было установлено по умолчанию - 'postgres'. Но, когда я ввожу в оболочке команду 'psql', то требуется пароль.. Я ввожу 'postgres' (пароль который я установил при инсталляции) и я не могу пройти потому что как оказалось он использует имя моего компьютера, а не postgres. И чтобы войти я должен вводить команду psql вместе с --username=='postgres'. И затем, вводя соответственно пароль postgres я вхожу в postgres=# (где и пытаюсь вводить вышеуказанные команды:

$ createdb  geodjango

$ psql geodjango > CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

)

Спасибо!

Comment: а че не Linux ?? граблей бы избежали бы

Answer (score 2):

В postgresql каждая команда должна завершаться точкой с запятой.

Новая строка выдаётся так как postgresql ожидает продолжения ввода команды

В вашем случае

```
$ createdb -T template_postgis geodjango;
```